# Access child in customized wxPanel

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, codeblocks

So I have a class MyPanel inherited from wxPanel:

```
 class MyPanel : public wxPanel
 {
       public:
          MyPanel(wxWindow* parent) : wxPanel(parent){}
          void OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event);
       private:
          DECLAER_EVENT_TABLE()
  };
```

and another main wxframe defined below:

```
 class mainFrame : public wxFrame
 {
       ...
       private:
          ...
          MyPanel* myPanel;
          ...
          wxStaticText* StaticText1;
          ...
 };
```

StaticText1 eventually will be assigned as the child of myPanel.
So I want to update mouse cursor's coordinates in the method OnMouseMove()

I am wondering how I can access to StaticText1 and update stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use friend declaration, like this:

```
class mainFrame : public wxFrame
{
  friend class MyPanel;
  ...
};
```

Comment: that is likely to work in codeblock+wxsmith.should i call statictext1(defined in mainframe) in void mypanel::onmousemove(wxMouseEvnet& event) like "mainFrame::StaticText1->SetLabel(x)" ? cuz i tried that and it failed

Comment: Friend declaration is a general C++ feature that has nothing to do with your UI library. This declaration allows any method of `MyPanel` access any data field/method/typedef/etc of `mainFrame`. Post exact code that is not working.

Comment: in `void MyPanel::OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event)`, I tried to access statictext like `mainFrame::StaticText1->SetLabel(string);`.This is not working and the compiler says "invalid use of nonstatic member" so i guess it is the way i access statictext1 is not correct.

Comment: The compiler is right. There can be several instances of `mainFrame` around. Most likely you have static variable of `mainFrame` class. Use something like `g_myMainFrameInstance->StaticText1(...)`.

Comment: could you explain a bit about `g_myMainFrame`?It looks like a private self defined wxframe instance in wxPanel.

Comment: It is hard to explain this in a comment. Read something about static and instance data members plus about the concept of the "object instantiation".

Comment: and i suppose that I should add one parameter in my OnMouseMove() function declaring a reference to mainFrame ?

Comment: This depends on how your whole app is organized. If you have just one mainframe in your app, then you should define mainframe as static var somewhere outside of any function.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a member in MyPanel and assign StaticText1 to it if needed.
In OnMouseMove check, if StaticText1 is NULL or not.

```
 class MyPanel : public wxPanel
  {
        public:
           MyPanel(wxWindow* parent) : wxPanel(parent){}
           void OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event) { if (StaticText1) { /* do something */ } ;
           void SetStaticText1(wxStaticText* txt) { StaticText1 = txt;}
        private:
           DECLAER_EVENT_TABLE()
           wxStaticText* StaticText1;

   };
```

Answer (score 0):

From a programming point of view you could use the friend solution. However logically, if wxStaticText* StaticText1 will be parented by MyPanel and mainly referenced/updated from within one of MyPanel's member functions. Then wxStaticText should ideally be declared and defined in MyPanel not in mainFrame.